# Null Pointer Exception implementing a find method for a doubly linked list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a find method for a doubly linked list.  When I run tests, i keep getting a null pointer exception on my find method.

```
    public int find(Medication item) {
    MedicationNode curr = head;
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
        if (curr.item.equals(item)){         //error occurs on this line
            return k;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The part of the test where I get a null pointer exception is here

```
        list.remove(m4);
    if (list.find(m4) != -1) {                  //error occurs on this line
        System.out.println("FAILURE");
        return;
```

I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this as my find method seems to be working otherwise

Comment: if (curr.item != null && curr.item.equals(item)) would be a bandage fix, are you sure about 'count' value being maintained correctly?

Comment: Where did you get the **count** variable and what is its value?

Comment: I think the problem is the count variable.  I'm still getting errors even after doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If your linkedList implementation is done by allowing your items to be `null`, then nullPointers can happen in your `find()`. Simply replace this

```
if (curr.item.equals(item)){
```

with this

```
if (curr.item != null && curr.item.equals(item)){
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no check in your find method to determine if there are any elements in your list. So, you need to first check that head or curr is not null before entering the for loop. Or, you are not properly tracking your count as Jimmy pointed out.

A better solution would be to not depend on count and check that curr.next is not null. Something like:

```
public int find(Medication item) {
    MedicationNode curr = head;
    while(curr != null){
        if (curr.item != null && curr.item.equals(item)){ 
            return k;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: this worked, my count variable definitely was the problem as I'm running into problems now with other tests which involve size()

Comment: Great, feel free to up-vote and mark the answer as correct. Good luck on your project :)